# assigning devices to operations in Tensorflow via attributes

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to assign the device after the operation has been created? so rather than use the with **tf.device(u'/gpu:1'**) for example we could use a **op.device = u'/gpu:1'** (obviosly this does not work but was wondering if there is something similar)

Note: **op** is a tensorflow operation where **type(op)** returns **tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation**

Thank you